# TimeSeries: Can't get the type = "o" to work, my data is only plotting horizontal lines for each data point when I need a connected line graph

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a time series graph, but am having issues getting it to be a line graph while showing the decades at the bottom.

My data set has the decades (as factors) next to performance (integer)

If I write

`plot(StockPerformance$Decade, StockPerformance$Performance)`

I will get a graph that has horizontal lines in it

[PLOT PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDtoh.png)

adding,

`type ="o"`

like this:

`plot(StockPerformance$Decade, StockPerformance$Performance, type ="o")`

doesn't change it....

Comment: Show us something that is reproducible.  Give us a subset of your real data (use `dput`).  You haven't even told us which function you used, since `plot` is a generic function, and the actual one depends on the type of the arguments...

Comment: I am sorry, this is me posting my first question. I used the function plot. how do I use dput?

Comment: Probably `StockPerformance` is a pretty large variable.  Shrink it to something manageable, then run `dput("StockPerformance")`.  R will print something that other people could use to recreate it, and then we could answer your question.

Comment: How to use `dput`? Search SO for "[r] great reproducible example". It will be the highest voted question. It's the R-centric version of [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

In R, when you read/create a data frame using `read.table` (or a variant thereof) or make it using `data.frame`, it tries to figure out what you have, and treat it appropriately.  Specifically, inputs with character vectors (like "1830s" get converted to factors.

Factors are a way to efficiently store character strings - which was a lot more important when R was first created than now.  The important thing for you is that characters don't have any order to them unless you put it there, so R automatically makes boxplots out of them.  That's why you are seeing lines - they are boxplots with only one point.

To get around this, you need to convert them to numbers for the purpose of plotting.  Then, you need to "fix" the axes afterwards.  Here's how:

```
plot(Performance ~ as.numeric(Decade),
  data = StockPerformance,
  xlab = "Decade", # otherwise we have "as.numeric(Decade)
  xaxt = 'n', # removes default axis ticks and labels
  pch = 1 # default open circle.  Change the number to get other options.  16 and 20 are both closed circles (20 is small, 16 is big)
)
with(StockPerformance, # This just makes it so I don't have to type StockPerformance twice below.
  axis(1, at = 1:nlevels(Decade),
    value = levels(Decade)
))
```